# Where does Azure Functions store the connection string to my External Table binding?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm playing around with [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/)' experimental External Table binding feature (binding type: "apiHubTable"). In my case I'm trying to output some data into a SQL Server table.

When I setup the output binding I create a new "External Connection" which is basically my SQL Server connections string:

[image]

I can give that connection a "Display Name" but when I'm done creating it, I find that the bindings 's "External Table connection" is pointing to something called "sql_SQL".

[image]

Turns out that "sql_SQL" is defined in the Function App's "App settings" as a URL that looks like:

> Endpoint=https://logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net/apim/sql/#REDACTED#/;Scheme=Key;AccessToken=#REDACTED#

What is this sort of endpoint URL? Where does "https://logic-apis-westeurope.azure-apim.net" come from? And most importantly - How can I edit / review my connection once it's been saved and linked to this way?

Answer (score 2):

Under the covers these external connections are implemented using an Api Hub.

Here is the implementation of the external table provider on github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/tree/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.ApiHub

This is the api hub sdk, which is what consumes the above connection string: https://github.com/Azure/azure-apihub-sdk

I'll see if I can dig up more on how to actually manage the connection (beyond modifying the appsetting directly).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any documentation on what an Azure ApiHub is?